# How do you get the list of existing markers on the videojs-markers plugin?

Tags: video.js

I feel this is a silly question so I apologize, but I have very little experience with JavaScripting in general.

I have an application where I want to allow users to annotate (mark) a video, so I am using https://github.com/spchuang/videojs-markers as a plugin to videojs, and it looks exactly what I need.

But after allowing the user to add markers, I want to record them on my database, so I need to be able to get the raw markers structure (i.e. with the time and text for each mark).

The code below shows what I have. It is the `recordMarks` function that I am having trouble with. That is where I want to get the marks in order for me to post them on my database via Ajax

```
//load the marker plugin
myPlayer.markers({
    ...
    markers: [
    ]
});

function markTime() {
    currentTime = getTime('Mark');

    myPlayer.markers.add([{
        time: currentTime,
        text: currentTime,
        overlayText: 'Tag',
        class: 'special-blue'
    }]);
    console.log('marked: ' + currentTime)
}

function recordMarks() {

    console.log(myPlayer.markers.markers);   // shows as Undefined
    // Try another way
    for(var i =0; i < myPlayer.markers.length; i++){
       console.log('mark ' + i + ' is ' + myPlayer.markers[i].text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the lack of solutions, I ended up declaring a global array of markers, such that every time I add the marker, I add it both to the global array, and to the player.